# Write output of a python script calling a sql script to a file

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I'm learning python and sql at the same time. ;)  The following python script calls a sql script.  I am trying to figure out how to get the output from the query to go to a csv.  I have gotten this far:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cx_Oracle
import sys
import csv
import os.path
import subprocess
con = cx_Oracle.connect('creden/tials@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host =server.work.net)(Port = 3453)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = SQLTEST)))')
cur=con.cursor()

f=open('/usr/local/src/sql/script_01.sql')
    full_sql=f.read()
    sql_commands=full_sql.split(";")
for sql_command in sql_commands:
    cur.execute(sql_command)

# Here is where the magic should happen
# The output of above should go to the 'test_query' file
query_results = <OUTPUT OF FOR LOOP>

c=csv.writer(open("/home/user/sqlplus/test_query/test_query.csv","w"),delimiter=";",lineterminator="\r\n")
c.writerows(query_results)

cur.close()
```

---

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Since we can't access your Oracle DB, we can't see what is going wrong.

Comment: The sql script is running fine, I just can't figure out how to direct the return of cur.execute(sql_command) to the csv.

Comment: You should fetch the results every time you execute something. So you can add something like `results = cur.fetchall()` and `query_results.append(results)` in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you. [Documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html)

There is function fetchall() which fetches all rows of query result.

You can use it as

```
cur.execute("sql_command")
query_result = cur.fetchall()
```

query_result will be of type tuple.

This will contain result of only one command at a time.

Now you can use list. And append all the results.

e.g.

```
results = []
for sql_command in sql_commands:
    cur.execute(sql_command) #sql_command is of type string
    query_result = cur.fetchall()
    print(query_result)
    #query_result will be tuple so select which part of the tuple you need. e.g query_result[0], query_result[1] etc.
    results.append(query_result[0]) #change index according to your need
```

Now at the end of for loop you will have list (i.e results) having all the outputs of query.

By using another for loop over results(which is a list) you can get the result of each query one by one 
and can write in csv file.

I don't now how to handle csv file. Maybe you need to save csv file at each iteration.
I hope you can handle this.